# consultas con sql server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

el enunciado es siguiente: obtén el nombre y el dni de los alumnos con la máxima nota en la asignatura con el código 46322

La estructura de la base de datos es esta:

```
alumnos (dni pk, nombre, dirección, localidad)
asignaturas (coda pk, nombreas, curso,dpt)
expedientes ((dni,coda)pk, y fk, convocatoria, nota)
```

**La consulta la he planteado así:**

```
select nombre, nombrea, convocatoria
from alumnos inner join expedientes on (expedientes.dni=alumnos.dni) inner join asignaturas on (asignaturas.coda=expedientes.coda)
where  exists (select max(nota)
              from expedientes
              where (coda=47322 ) and (convocatoria like 'junio') );
```

Sin embargo me devuelve valores incorrectos. Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El query debería ser:

```
Select a.nombre, a.dni, max(e.nota) as Maxima
from alumnos a 
Inner join expedientes e on e.dni=a.dni
where e.coda=47322 
group by a.nombre, a.dni
```

Comment: No vi la actualización, ya funciona gracias